# Vertically centering text in a responsive manner

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Been making progress on a personal web design project, but I keep getting stuck at vertically centering a `p` tag inside a `section`.

https://jsfiddle.net/dowp4rv3/1/

I want the text inside this section to be centered vertically, but I don't want to lose any responsiveness. I've tried a number of possible solutions, but I keep screwing up precisely that. Do any of you experts see a quick fix?

html

```
<div class="box">
  <section>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

css

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.box section {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid .2em white;
}

.box section p {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
}


}

}
```

There's definitely superfluous css in there (partially due to artefacts from the project that I took this out of), but the problem I'm having can be seen.

Comment: where's the problem, it's centered ?

Comment: I want the text to be centered vertically in section. So equal distance from top and bottom border.

Comment: ah sorry, I thought about the section itself...

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good resource on centering things - https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Using your existing CSS, you can apply `top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` on the `p` element to center it vertically.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.box section {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid .2em white;
}

.box section p {
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <section>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

You can also use `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;` on the `p`'s parent to center the `p` horizontally and vertically

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
}

.box section {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid .2em white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box section p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <section>
    <p>Some text</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! You have no idea how long I've been fiddling with this thing to get it to work. Lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the `section`a flexbox container with the following settings (which makes all the settings for the included `p`tag superfluous):

```
.box section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20%;
  width: 70%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid .2em white;
}
```

complete solution see here: https://jsfiddle.net/7ag8jqtu/